# Storing Encoded Unicode string into Postgres but retrieving different random string

Tags: python, postgresql, unicode

I have a python server that is storing user data into a postgres table. I started using SQLite for my db and had no issues, but upon converting to postgres I ran into a problem storing unicode encoded strings for my `encr_password`.

`CREATEuser` stores this data:

`{'fname': ['John'], 'encr_password': [b'$2b$14$NvAJc1nxSRpQnuK5iAUxyeMN9wobMShjUYxCpANlsYUn8M1qir1Tq'], 'email': ['john@doe.com'], 'lname': ['Doe']}`

But when retrieving the data from my Postgres server I receive:

```
[{'encr_password': '\\x243262243134244675375137324b4953614c5a70706354355a756d712e77433365576d42554e4f47315a486c43593958353454474248494969726b43', 'fname': 'John', 'user_id': 1, 'email': 'john@doe.com', 'lname': 'Doe'}]
```

Again my retrieval returned exactly what I expected and stored in its initial form when using SQLite.

- Python Server 3.5.2
- Bcrypt 3.1.1

Comment: If your "unicode encoded string" actually contained arbitrary binary data, as it looks like, it wasn't really text to start with. You should *either* stop using text for `encr_password`, or you should use a text-friendly way of encoding the data, such as hex or base64.

Comment: From what I read abt bcrypt it hashes the password & salt into base64. I believe I just pre-encoded it to UTF-8 for a validation check later per required by the bcrypt library. So is it wrong to save it as a VARCHAR(255) in my db if I remove the encoding until it is required? p.s. Thanks for answering my question already and responding so quickly!

Comment: That's *not* base64. I wouldn't expect a bcrypt function to convert it into base64 automatically... the output is simply binary data. You should use base64 yourself to convert that into appropriate text.

Comment: It looks likely that the password is stored in `bytea` form, and you're retrieving it in its default hex format. Show output of `\d tablename` in `psql`.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're shoving base64-format data into a `bytea` field. You don't need to do that. Either supply the binary in octal-escape form, or hex-escape form, [per the PostgreSQL manual](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/datatype-binary.html).

If you must encode it as base64, store it in a `text` field. Or use the `encode` and `decode` functions to transform the base64 to/from bytea on input and output.